# I want store value in file and read it using php

Tags: php, file

here I have value stored in $value1 variable and I want to store it's value in valuebxb.txt, and again I want to read that value from valuebxb.txt and store it to another variable $value2, here is a code from which I was able to create required file, but not able to store the value.

```
$value1 = round($value1, 4);
      if (!file_exists('valuebxb.txt')) {
            touch('valuebxb.txt', strtotime('-1 days'));  //file is created
            $file = fopen("valuebxb.txt","w");            //opening the file
            fwrite($file,$value1);                        //storing the value of variable in file
            fclose($file);                                //closing the file
        }
```

Comment: According to your code, value is only stored if the file does not exist.

Comment: I would recommend using [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) instead. They are much easier to use for reading and writing to files.

Comment: ok, i need to put it in else too

Comment: @MagnusEriksson will it replace the old value when storing the new value?

Comment: That depends on what you tell it to do. `file_put_contents('path/to/file', 'thevalue')` will replace the contents (and create the file if it doesn't exist). If you want it to append instead, then add that flag: `file_put_contents('path/to/file', 'thevalue', FILE_APPEND)`. It's all explained in the manual.

Comment: I've posted an answer with some examples.

Comment: Thank you @MagnusEriksson, it solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) instead. They are much easier to use for reading and writing to files.

In your case, to write to a file:

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/file', $theValue);
```

(this will also create the file if it doesn't already exist)

And to read the value from the file:

```
// Define the variable with a default value
$value = null;

// Read from the file if it exists
if (is_file('/path/to/file')) {
    $value = file_get_contents('/path/to/file');
}
```

A shorter version of reading using ternary:

```
$value = is_file('/path/to/file') ? file_get_contents('/path/to/file') : null;
```